# php subscription success text not working properly

Tags: php, email, system, subscription, sender

Okay so basically i have this subscription input where people enter their email and click a button... Once they click the button the company email gets notified of the new subscriber (it receives a email and in the email states the email the user inputted)... anyways i've got it working so it does that and also writes whatever the user inputted into a .txt file.. Its all working but after i successfully got it to write to the text file, the success text after clicking the subscribe button dosent show...

HTML:

```
        <div class="span12 subscribe">
            <h3>Subscribe to our newsletter</h3>
            <p>Sign up now to our newsletter and you'll be one of the first to know when the site is ready:</p>
            <form class="form-inline" action="assets/sendmail.php" method="post">
                <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Enter your email...">
                <button type="submit" class="btn">Subscribe</button>
            </form>
            <div class="success-message"></div>
            <div class="error-message"></div>
        </div>
```

PHP:

```
<?php


// Email address verification

function isEmail($email) {
    return(preg_match("/^[-_.[:alnum:]]+@((([[:alnum:]]|[[:alnum:]][[:alnum:]-]*[[:alnum:]])\.)+(ad|ae|aero|af|ag|ai|al|am|an|ao|aq|ar|arpa|as|at|au|aw|az|ba|bb|bd|be|bf|bg|bh|bi|biz|bj|bm|bn|bo|br|bs|bt|bv|bw|by|bz|ca|cc|cd|cf|cg|ch|ci|ck|cl|cm|cn|co|com|coop|cr|cs|cu|cv|cx|cy|cz|de|dj|dk|dm|do|dz|ec|edu|ee|eg|eh|er|es|et|eu|fi|fj|fk|fm|fo|fr|ga|gb|gd|ge|gf|gh|gi|gl|gm|gn|gov|gp|gq|gr|gs|gt|gu|gw|gy|hk|hm|hn|hr|ht|hu|id|ie|il|in|info|int|io|iq|ir|is|it|jm|jo|jp|ke|kg|kh|ki|km|kn|kp|kr|kw|ky|kz|la|lb|lc|li|lk|lr|ls|lt|lu|lv|ly|ma|mc|md|mg|mh|mil|mk|ml|mm|mn|mo|mp|mq|mr|ms|mt|mu|museum|mv|mw|mx|my|mz|na|name|nc|ne|net|nf|ng|ni|nl|no|np|nr|nt|nu|nz|om|org|pa|pe|pf|pg|ph|pk|pl|pm|pn|pr|pro|ps|pt|pw|py|qa|re|ro|ru|rw|sa|sb|sc|sd|se|sg|sh|si|sj|sk|sl|sm|sn|so|sr|st|su|sv|sy|sz|tc|td|tf|tg|th|tj|tk|tm|tn|to|tp|tr|tt|tv|tw|tz|ua|ug|uk|um|us|uy|uz|va|vc|ve|vg|vi|vn|vu|wf|ws|ye|yt|yu|za|zm|zw)$|(([0-9][0-9]?|[0-1][0-9][0-9]|[2][0-4][0-9]|[2][5][0-5])\.){3}([0-9][0-9]?|[0-1][0-9][0-9]|[2][0-4][0-9]|[2][5][0-5]))$/i", $email));
}

if($_POST) {

    // Enter the email where you want to receive the notification when someone subscribes
    $emailTo = 'subscriptions@servready.com';

    $subscriber_email = ($_POST['email']);

    if(!isEmail($subscriber_email)) {
        $array = array();
        $array['valid'] = 0;
        $array['message'] = 'Insert a valid email address!';
        echo json_encode($array);
    }
    else {
        $array = array();
        $array['valid'] = 1;
        $array['message'] = 'Thanks for your subscription!';
        echo json_encode($array);

        // Send email
    $subject = 'New Subscriber!';
    $body = "You have a new subscriber!\n\nEmail: " . $subscriber_email;
        // uncomment this to set the From and Reply-To emails, then pass the $headers variable to the "mail" function below
    $headers = "From: ".$subscriber_email." <" . $subscriber_email . ">" . "\r\n" . "Reply-To: " . $subscriber_email;
    mail($emailTo, $subject, $body, $headers);
    }

    $data = $_POST['email']."\n";
    $ret = file_put_contents('data.txt', $data, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
    if($ret === false) {
        die('There was an error writing this file');
    }
    else {
        echo "$ret bytes written to file";
    }

}
?>
```

If i remove this part of the php script, the success and invalid email text pops up:

```
$data = $_POST['email']."\n";
$ret = file_put_contents('data.txt', $data, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
if($ret === false) {
    die('There was an error writing this file');
}
else {
    echo "$ret bytes written to file";
}
```

Like i said, its functional, but the success text or invalid email errors and success texts don't pop up with the code that writes the persons emails to the text file.

Site is http://servready.com for testing

Comment: You echo the array, then one way or another you echo more text... That text (die or echo at the end) causes the array for JS to break.

Comment: so remove the if and else? @JeremyMiller

Comment: Or take whatever other action you want -- echoing out text after (or before) the serialized JSON object just breaks the JSON data received client-side.  Want me to post this as an answer?

Comment: yes thank you it works noww!! @JeremyMiller also would you happen to know how to change the time of the countdown? and also for some reason whenever the user refreshes the page the countdown resets and starts again... pretty annoying, i wouldn't expect you to know why that's happening though.. just asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per the comments above, it is the content being echoed out after `echo json_encode` -- the extra content breaks the JSON echoed out causing everything else to break.

http://servready.com/assets/js/scripts.js is the JS file with your countdown time in it -- it's hardcoded into the script, so that's why it starts over.  You'd need to put some code in there to determine the appropriate time for the countdown to reflect.  I sugget you give that a try and then post a followup question with any issues you may need assistance with.

Glad to help!

Comment: Thanks for the help, but im sort of noob when it comes to php, so I can't find myself figuring that part out... Thanks for the help though! @JeremyMiller

Comment: The script I linked to is Javascript.  Just search for countdown and take a look at the code.  Also, if this was the answer to your question, please accept it.  Just click the checkmark on the top-left of the question.